# Visual Studio 2010 freezes when creating new SPA controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-spa

I've just started using the new ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta stuff and whenever I try to create a new controller VS2010 freezes, anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you applied the latest service Pack through windows update [Download here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691)?

Please follow these threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016263/error-when-adding-view-in-mvc-3),  [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016263/error-when-adding-view-in-mvc-3)

Answer (score 0):

Define "freezes". It will normally take several moments for all the SPA template's NuGet packages to install.